# Passing database values to new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm using a database example as a reference to help me create a mobile app for school, and have run into a problem. I'm using a listView to store all of my fields into and I would like to have it display in a new activity. Right now, the EditTexts are all lined up vertically on the main screen with the listView being displayed at the bottom of the screen, but I would like it to be displayed on a different screen when a button is clicked. The second activity is displaying all of the information correctly, but so is the listView on the main screen. When I try to get rid of the listView on the main screen, it doesn't work. Any help to point me in the right direction would be great!

In my activity_main, I have the listView at the bottom of the screen as follows:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contactlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And I also declared it in my activity_display_database layout where I would like it to show up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my main activity is as follows, where I'm actually getting the error when I delete the listView from my main xml file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<PhoneBook> contactList;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView name, number, address, orderTotal, amountReceived, tip, mileage, grandTotal;
    private Button add;
    private PhonebookAdapter adapter;
    PhoneBookHandler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);

        db = new PhoneBookHandler(this);

        contactList = db.getAllContacts();

        adapter = new PhonebookAdapter(this, contactList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        orderTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
        amountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
        tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
        mileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
        grandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

        String cName = name.getText().toString();
        String num = number.getText().toString();
        String cAddress = address.getText().toString();
        String cOrderTotal = orderTotal.getText().toString();
        String cAmountReceived = amountReceived.getText().toString();
        String cTip = tip.getText().toString();
        String cMileage = mileage.getText().toString();
        String cGrandTotal = grandTotal.getText().toString();

        int id = db.addContact(new PhoneBook(cName, num, cAddress, cOrderTotal,
                                          cAmountReceived, cTip, cMileage, cGrandTotal));
        contactList.add(new PhoneBook(id, cName, num, cAddress, cOrderTotal,
                                   cAmountReceived, cTip, cMileage, cGrandTotal));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void buttonClickFunction(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), display_database.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to get the code to where the database entries will be displayed in the activity_display_database xml file, but not on the main screen. Whenever I try to delete the listView from the main screen, I get an error in my main's onCreate method. Thank you for your time. Anyone that can help me, I would be greatly appreciative!

EDIT: The error I'm getting from logcat is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.boley.databaseexample/com.example.boley.databaseexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.boley.databaseexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, no problem. I updated my question with the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the main list view,you need to get rid of the the `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` line of code. The reason you get that error when you get rid of the list view in the xml is because you get rid of the listview reference and then when you call your main method, the object is null. The reason that you don't get a compile error is because you have another listview with that same id. If you were to change your listview in the database xml to something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactlist_database"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then deleted the main activity xml file, you'd get a compiler error. I hope that this makes sense. If you want to set just the database list view, then you need to call that listview and set the adapter in your second activity.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure why I'm only getting the error when I comment out the listView from my main xml file. In my display_database java file, all I did was copy and paste the contents from the Main Activity's onCreate method. And even with both Main's and activity_display_database's xml files having the same id name for the listView, they will both function properly. I'm just trying to delete the listView from my Main xml, but that's when it throws the error.

Comment: I told you why get the error when you comment out the listview in the main xml. I also told you how to solve it. If you comment out the listview in the main xml, then comment out the line `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` in the `onCreate` method, you will be able to run the program. Commenting out the listview in your main xml creates a null pointer exeption. To keep from getting that, you get rid of the `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` in main's `oncreate` method

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't see your edit. That worked perfect! That's been driving me nuts for two weeks now. I just wanted to make sure I couldn't find the answer anywhere before I came here. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data using objects, create an instance of class A in class B. For example : 
You have two classes class A and class B

```
Class A {
 public int id = YourID;

 public int getId()
  return id;
 }
```

And in the second class you can use the id like this:

```
Class B{

    A a = new A();
    int recievedId = a.getId // Now the id is saved in recievedId attribute        

}
```

Hope that helps